# What is wrong with this code of multiplying two numbers?

Tags: c, multiplication

I have tried storing the first number in an array and then multiplying each digit of that number with the second one and storing the carry seperately in temp variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,b,temp,a,count=0,arr[1000];
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    while(a!=0)
    {
        arr[++i]=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        count++;
    }
    temp=0;
    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        temp=arr[j]*b+temp;
        arr[j]=temp%10;
        temp=temp/10;
    }

    while(temp>0)
    {
        arr[++j]=temp%10;
        count++;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
    for(i=count;i>0;i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not working, be more specific.

Comment: Tip: `++i` and `i++` are not the same thing.

Comment: The last loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: @CoolGuy, temp looks like a monotonically decreasing value to me ... the loop will terminate

Comment: @HexedAgain , The **last** loop. Not the second last one!

Comment: ah ... I stand corrected ... didn't see the one-liner of death there!

Answer (score 2):

By using the expression `arr[++i]`, you are **first** incrementing `i`, and **then** setting the array's value. Therefore, the value of `arr[0]` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

- `arr[++i]=a%10;` means if i is 0 and a is 11, you are storing 1 at index 1 rather than 0. So you should use `arr[i++]=a%10;` post increment operator.
- `for(i=count;i>0;i++)` means you start with say count as 4, you check for i greater than 0 and keep on incrementing (and with every loop you satisfy the condition) leading to infinite loop. You should rather decrement the i value as `for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--)` and iterate till array index 0.

Comment: The loop isn't right. Array indices start from 0 and end at **length-1**

Comment: Thanks.It worked. And sorry to bother for such silly mistakes.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh No worries. Make sure you close this question by accepting the answer if it has helped you, so others can benefit in future.

Answer (score 0):

Change you last loop.

From

```
for(i=count;i>0;i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
```

To

```
for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
```

put
`i=count-1` in your loop because in the last iteration of `while(temp>0){}` you are setting the value to count++(lengthOfArray+1) and you are ignoring it in your last for loop.And also put `i>=0` because you are not printing 0th position value. And also `i--`.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/2L1e3v)